# Delete hidden, read-only files

Tags: powershell

I have a powerscript that deletes the read-only files using this syntax. My question is does the file deleted without unchecking the read-only attribute behind the scenes? We have an application that consumes the non read-only files and set to read-only once done.

PowerShell: Remove-Item -Path C:\Test\hidden-RO-file.txt -Force
OS: Microsoft Windows[Version 10

Comment: The readonly filesystem attribute governs the _contents_ of the file - you can't append to (or delete data from) the file, but the file object itself can still be deleted or renamed within the filesystem. UI warnings on soft deletion of read-only files in Explorer is a feature of the Windows recycle bin, not the file system itself.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks. It's deleted without unchecking the read-only attribute, right? When I tried deleting it manually, the file in the recycle bin was still read-only and that is what behavior I wanted to avoid the other application to consume it again.

Comment: I don't know for certain, but I don't think so. `Remove-Item` is comparable to a permanent delete (Shift + Del), not a soft delete (aka move to recycle bin)

Answer (score 0):

See: https://darwinsdata.com/how-to-forcefully-delete-a-folder-in-windows-using-powershell/

Yes, your script is effectively permanently removing the read-only files without needing to change their attributes first. Please ensure you use this command carefully as it will delete the specified files without any error checking.